# Pre-populate a lot of radio button group from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm working on a project. I want to pre-populated data from database.

**HTML**

```
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" <?php echo $checkedA ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" <?php echo $checkedB ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" <?php echo $checkedC ?>>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" <?php echo $checkedA ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B" <?php echo $checkedB ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="C" <?php echo $checkedC ?>>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A" <?php echo $checkedA ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="B" <?php echo $checkedB ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="C" <?php echo $checkedC ?>>
</div>
<!-- etc till let's say 30 question -->
```

**PHP**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `quiz` WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++){
  switch($data[${"answer".$i}]{
   case "A" : $checkedA="checked"; break;
   case "B" : $checkedB="checked"; break;
   case "C" : $checkedC="checked"; break;
  }
}
```

Then, how to make the q1 which is corresponded with $data['answer1'] checked if it is filled with data from database, etc?

Comment: You can check out my answer!. If there is anything else, just reply here and I can do my best to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code you've provided, It's viable to get the data from the database and then show the result in your html and not over complicate things. To pre-populate your radio buttons, you need to have the following below:

**PHP**

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `quiz` WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" <?php echo ($data['q1'] == 'A')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" <?php echo ($data['q1'] == 'B')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" <?php echo ($data['q1'] == 'C')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" <?php echo ($data['q2'] == 'A')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B" <?php echo ($data['q2'] == 'B')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="C" <?php echo ($data['q2'] == 'C')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
</div>
<div class="question">
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A" <?php echo ($data['q3'] == 'A')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="B" <?php echo ($data['q3'] == 'B')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="C" <?php echo ($data['q3'] == 'C')? 'checked' : '';  ?>>
</div>
```

With that piece of code, it sets *checked* depending on what the value coming from the database is and displays it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Example has exactly 3 variables for checked (`$checkedA`, `$checkedB`, `$checkedC`). In order to have 3 varsiables *per question*, it would need a *collection* of "checks". If you have *n* questions, your collection needs *n* members. And each of those members needs 3 members representing whether the answer is checked, one for each option.

As an example: 
If the answer to q1 is A, then 
 `$checked['q1'] = ['A'=> "checked",'B'=>"",'C'=>""]`.

In the php, initialize a `$checked` member for each question as described above. Then change the `switch` to update the corresponding member. [The reason to initialize this way is because 1) everything needs a value in the html and 2) `checked` is a boolean attribute]

The html would echo `$checked[q#]['A']` `$checked[q#]['B']` and `$checked[q#]['C']` respectively.